# Does the LilyGo TTGO T-Camera Plus ESP32 dev board have a speaker?

Tags: esp32

Related question : [(Dev) board to develop my own Amazon Ring(tm) -like doorbell](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14078/dev-board-to-develop-my-own-amazon-ringtm-like-doorbell).

I am unable to find out if the TTGO T-Camera Plus has a speaker, though which I could play audio which the ESP32 receives over the internet. Does anyone know?

(any help on the related question would also be welcome ;-)

Comment: there is no mention of a speaker ... the pictures of the board do show that there is no onboard speaker

Comment: Feel free to post that an answer, then. Do you know if it would be possible to add one - preferably without soldering? e.g via Grove connector. Or, can you answer my related question & suggest an alternative?

Comment: Searching for “grove speaker” should yield what you are looking for. You may also want to consider the m5stack products, I’m pretty sure there’s a combination of base/stick/atom, hat and or unit that would do everything you need.

Comment: Upvaote. I already have a lot of M5 stack stuph. ***BUT***,  can you work that up iinto an answer?